# Not able to move cursor to the beginning of textbox/rich text area due to focus loss using selenium WebDriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox, automation

I have to enter 8 digit number in two text box's using selenium web driver c#. I can enter that number using Keyboard.sendkeys but sometimes due to focus loss i can not set text in those text box's. Please have a look at the attached image. So i have to first click in the beginning of the text box first then i have try by entering value.

please help ...because when i click normally in the text box then click focus is getting set to middle of text box due to which half value is getting entered and some part is lost of that number . Please help ....

Note: This issue is getting on Virtual machines only. On my physical machine it is working properly.

I have used below code to enter ..but facing digit loss while entering and focus loss issue:

```
Random rnd = new System.Random();
string number= 0 + rnd.Next(11111111, 99999999).ToString();
Logger.LogInfo("Enter Number");
Driver.FindElement(GlobalEnums.FindBy.Id, Id_Txb).SendKeys(number);
Logger.LogInfo("Re-Enter  Number");
Keyboard.SendKeys("{TAB}");                                                Driver.FindElement(GlobalEnums.FindBy.Id, Id_Txb_ConfirmSSN).SendKeys(number);
```

Or can we move cursor to first location in the text box after click action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you want to focus or blur something, do not rely on the events happening as a side effect of something else (e.g. focus happening when clicking, or blur happening when something else is focused).

Instead you should explicitly trigger those events via JavaScript. Examples:

```
IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("$('#foo').focus()");
js.ExecuteScript("$('#foo').blur()");
```

Other way to try is:

```
IWebElement testDiv = WebDriver.FindElement( By.Id( "someID" ) );            
Actions builder = new Actions( WebDriver );
Actions hoverClick = builder.MoveToElement( testDiv ).MoveByOffset( x, y ).Click();
hoverClick.Build().Perform();
```